# How to keep value in array format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array stored inside input hidden field as follow:

```
<input type='text' name='fileuploaddelete' id='fileuploaddelete' class='required' value='["ppl.jpg","Tulips.jpg","Penguins.jpg"]'/>
```

JS

```
var deleteFile = [];
deleteFile = $("#fileuploaddelete").val(); // return string format
```

When I retrieved the value using jquery, it is in String format. How to keep it in array format? Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()` to retrieve `Object` (`Array` in this case) from `String`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y10sa1t/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
parsedTest = JSON.parse( $("#fileuploaddelete").val());// this will convert it into array
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

> "

and

> []

before setting the value.
Then you can use:

```
$("#fileuploaddelete").val().split(',');
```

This should return the value in array format.

Comment: What about removing `"`, `[` and `]` before voting up?

Comment: Someone upvoted your answer while it is not actually correct one: instead of `ppl.jpg`, `Tulips.jpg`, `Penguins.jpg` you got `["ppl.jpg"`, `"Tulips.jpg"`, `"Penguins.jpg"]`

Comment: Yes, you are right. He has to remove these unnecessary characters before setting the value.

Comment: So we come to two thoughts: 1. Your answer is incomplete one. 2. Does it make sense to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = JSON.parse(deleteFile);
```